# Django - Show list of purchases in user's profile - include template with list from another app

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, paypal-subscriptions

I'm doing a project with Django and I'm using PayPal subscriptions. When you buy a product it saves the details in the Purchases table (by the way, it writes the purchase 3 times in the DB, but that's for another question). 
Now I'm trying to show a list of purchases in the user's profile template. I have a purchases template with the list and it works when I see it through its own URL, but whenever I try to show it in other templates it's just blank.

This is my structure:

- Apps: Account, Product, PayPal
- Models: User(custom), Product, Purchase
- Templates: profile, products, purchases, paypal_return/cancel,...
- Views: register, login, logout, all_products, paypal_return/cancel,...
- templatetags/products_extra: paypal_form_for, and right now a simple_tag with purchases_list (I also tried with just a view in products/views.py)

And my questions are:

1. Should I have a different app for purchases?
2. What is the best way to build the purchases list and show it in a template in another app? I've read loads of posts and documentation and tried just including the template {% include.. %}, with simple_tags, with template inheritance, inclusion tags... but I cannot make it work.

Below is the code I have right now.

Thank you in advance!

models.py

```
class Purchase (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='purchases')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    license_end = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

templatetags/product_extras.py

```
@register.simple_tag
def purchases_list(request):
    purchases = Purchase.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products/purchases.html', {'purchases': purchases})
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^purchases/$', product_extras.purchases_list, name='purchases'),
```

purchases.html

```
    <p>PURCHASES</p>
        {% for purchase in purchases %}
            <p>{{purchase.id}}-{{ purchase.product }} - {{ purchase.license_end }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
```

profile.html

```
    {% include "products/purchases.html" %}
```

Comment: What templates do purchases.html and profile.html inherit from?

Comment: profile inherits from base.html (header and footer of the website mainly) and purchases doesn't inherits from any.  I've tried inheriting from profile and creating a {% block %} but couldn't make it work either

Comment: Can you show us the view code you use to draw the profile page? You have to set the purchases variable there with the content you want it to render. I don't think a custom template tag is good solution in this situtation.

Comment: The view is just 

`def profile(request):
        return render(request, 'profile.html')`

And the profile only has

    `{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        {% include "products/purchases.html" %}
    {% endblock %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your info, my solution to your problem is to change your profile view to this:

```
def profile(request):
    purchases = Purchases.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', {'purchases':purchases})
```

When you include a template in another template you have to think that it is only a copy/paste operation. In order for it to render properly you have to provide the appropriate context variables, in this case `purchases`.

In addition, I believe you may want to improve your view further by showing only the purchases of the current logged user.

Edit:

If you want to do it using template tags, you may take a look at [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). They seem perfect for your use case.

I can not think of a way to do this using template inheritance. Inheritance is more suitable for things like defining a fixed header and footer.

Comment: That worked and makes total sense. Can I pass more than one context variables in that way? e.g. I want to show also the support cases for that `user in the profile page.  return render(request, 'account/profile.html',{'purchases':purchases, 'cases':cases}`
Just out of curiosity, is there any other way to do it (simple_tags, temp inheritance,...) or only with the include tag? 

About your addition, yes, of course, I was just trying to understand the logic first so I made it simpler :)

Thank you!

Comment: You can pass as many variables as you wish. Your example is perfectly valid. Concerning your other questions, check the edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!
Just one more thing. If I want to show only one item, e.g. the last purchase and I define the view/inclusion tag as: 
`def spss_last_purchase(request):
    last_purchase = Purchase.objects.last()
    print "HOLA"
    return {'last_purchase':last_purchase}`
How do I show that in the template if I don't have a for loop as it's a single item? 
Thanks again!

Comment: You can build another template where you use that variable directly: {{ last_purchase.id }}, {{ last_purchase.product }}, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your purchases.html remove the template tags:

```
{% block purchasess %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was from when I was trying template inheritance. I just removed them but still not showing anything in profile template